# Why is redux store's object property value from firestore '9' instead of img url?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, firebase-storage, react-native-ios

When a screen loads in my react-native application, I use a url from redux store, populated by firestore read operation (image stored in firebase-storage) as the sources for an image component. If I create the image's source prop like `source={{ui:this.props.someURL}}`, I get

`TypeError: NSNull cannot be converted to NSString`

Ok, I know this is a known issue regarding image's source props. I try to fix it with:

```
source={{ 
  uri: this.props.profileImg == null ?
  require('../assets/img/white-user.png') : 
  this.props.profileImg
}}
```

then I get the error from the question title: 
`JSON value '9' of type NSNumber cannot be converted to NSString`
If I completely remove the image component in question, no error.

the logged value of `this.props.someURL` inside constructor = `null`

the logged value of `this.props.someURL` inside `componentDidMount()` = null

As expected, because the values are populated by promises. So why is the `JSON value of '9'` error? this is only in iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your source props

From

```
source={{ 
    uri: this.props.profileImg == null ?
    require('../assets/img/white-user.png') : 
    this.props.profileImg
}}
```

To

```
source={
    this.props.profileImg == null ?
    require('../assets/img/white-user.png') : {
        uri:this.props.profileImg
    } 
}
```